# Dynamics CRM authentication through web application

Tags: rest, authentication, dynamics-crm

We try to get data from CRM Dynamics on premise from a web application. We have a specific AD account that can be used to get datas from the CRM.

We registered the application in ADFS to get a client ID. We tried to authenticate using the client ID and login/password of dedicated user. But no luck.

There is a lot of documentation available for this type of requests but all for Dynamics online. I could read some tutorials but no one could help us reach the goal.